# Getting a nil response while trying to clone a object to backpack

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to clone an object from the replicatedstorage to the players backpack when an object part is touched and the code looks fine for me but it keeps giving a nil response from `clone.parent = player.backpack`

```
local replicatedtorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Sword = replicatedtorage:FindFirstChild("Sword")

local part =  game.Workspace.Part

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local clone = Sword:Clone()

part.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local humanoid = hit.parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
if humanoid ~= nil then
    clone.Parent = player.Backpack
end
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a server `Script` which cannot access `Players.LocalPlayer` like clients can because there is no local player to the server. A way to get the `Player` that touched a part is through [Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Players/GetPlayerFromCharacter) which requires one instance to be passed and will either return the `Player` whose Character is that instance or `nil`.

```
part.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local character = hit.Parent
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(character)
    if player then
        clone.Parent = player.Backpack
    end
end)
```

This should work right away in your script and can replace your existing `Touched` connection.